# Which is true for a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\in (o,\frac{1}{n})$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $(x_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers such that for every $n,x_n\in (0,\frac{1}{n})$ then which of the following is true?

$1.\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$

$2.$If $f$ is continuous function from $\\(0,1)$ then $\\(f(x_n))$ is a cauchy sequence.

$3.$If $g$ is uniformly continuous function on $(0,1)$ then $g(x_n)$ is convergent.

My Try:First option we can prove by Squeeze theorem.

$2$nd is false take $\\A=(0,1),f(x)=\frac{1}{x},x_n=\frac{1}{2n}$

Is this correct?

About last option I have no idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I will show that 3) is correct.

Since $g(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$, it has a continuous extension to $[0,1]$.  Now since $\lim x_n = 0, g(x_n) \to g(0)$.

Comment: No this is wrong.$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$ but $0\notin (0,1/n)$ so $x_n$ is not convergent.So you can not say that $g(x_n)\to g(0)$

Comment: @Flip - $x_n$ is convergent in $[0,1]$. Mustafa's answer is perfectly right.

Comment: @Lierre but I have open interval,it is not closed.

Comment: @Flip The key point is the sentence “it has a continuous extension to [0,1]”. Do you understand it?

Comment: @Lierre sorry but I do not understand.Can you tell me some theorem about this?